# Magento 2: Cannot getData from different controller

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento2.4

I have this class

```
class Api extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \MyModule\Payment\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->contentType = $this->helper->getConfigData('content_type');
    }
    .
    .
    .
    function createOnlinePurchase($authToken, $lastOrder)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        //here I pass lastOrder's increment id to my payment gateway
        $lastOrder->setData('test','test data');
        $lastOrder->save();
        
        //make payment gateway api call, get payment url
        return url;
    }

}
```

this class is then used by a custom controller:

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \MyModule\Payment\Model\Api $moduleApi,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->moduleApi = $moduleApi;
        $this->session = $session;
    }
   
 public function execute() {
       $token = $this->moduleApi->requestAuthToken();

       if ($this->session->getLastRealOrder() && $token !== null) {
            $url = $this->moduleApi->createOnlinePurchase($token, $this->session->getLastRealOrder());

            if ($url !== null && substr($url, 0, 4) == 'http') {
               $this->session->clearStorage();     
               return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl($url);
            } 
            else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__("Url invalid: ".$url));
                return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/onepage/failure');
            }
       }
}
```

on a SECOND custom controller `Callback`, which is triggered by my payment gateway, I retrieved the order object using `$order = $this->getOrderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($incrementId)`

where `$this->getOrderFactory` is an instance of `\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory` I injected.

I got the `increment id` back from my payment gateway.

Somehow within this `Callback` class, when I use `$order->getData('test')`, I get nothing

**My question is**

Is there some core magento concept I'm missing here?

Or is there any other way I can retrieve this test data in `Callback` which only have the information of `increment Id` (because at the point of Callback, user have already left magento and come back)

It's weird to me beause I can edit and save the order from `Callback` but my extra data is not saved/associated with the order object itself

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I confirmed that I'm getting the same order object(row) by using the `order id` I get from my payment gateway as the one from `session's Last Order`

I called `addStatusHistoryComment` on `lastOrder` in Api class above and also called `addStatusHistoryComment` in my Callback class
both calls are updating the same order in my admin dashboard

I have also confirmed calling `getData('test')` right after I set it gives me the data I want.

So I don't understand why getData doesn't work when called from Callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just add data to order object, every model is mapped automatically to DB tables columns, object will store temporarily the data and not error out  but it will not persist in database. The reason why comments work, is because they have a place in database and on save and on load there is extra code that saves and adds it to the model.

In order to persists new data in the order you need to add new order attribute or simply add a new column on sales order table. When saving, key much match exactly the name of the new column you created.

Comment: You are welcome @rayjonathan10. If you think answer is correct feel free to mark as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `setCustomerNote` in place of `setData` with a custom key, which is weird that it works because it is literally doing:

`return $this->setData(OrderInterface::CUSTOMER_NOTE, $customerNote);`

I can only assume on magento 2.4.x (which is what i'm using btw), `setData` is restricted to predefined keys only.